# Why doesn't this javascript replace work? (contains no regex)

Tags: javascript, replace, alert

Here is the code:

```
 alert(oldVars);
 alert("change "+prevNumber+" to "+newNumber)
 newVars = oldVars.replace(prevNumber,newNumber);
 alert(newVars);
```

`oldVars` is a string containing some text and a number, e.g. `"Product ID 39203"`.

`prevNumber` is for example `39203`

I want to change `39203` to `200`. `newNumber` is set to `200`.

The alert for `oldVars` shows `"Product ID 39203"`.

The alert for `"change"` shows `"change 39203 to 200"`

The alert for `newVars` never shows up, so I'm assuming there's a mistake in the replace code. But what is the mistake? Why isn't my code working?

My aim is to have `"Product ID 200"`

I am using variables instead of strings/integers because the numbers vary from category to category, so I can't type in the numbers statically because I don't know what they are.

It worked here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace

Just not in my code...

Comment: Works fine - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtztV/)

Comment: Did you bother to look in the error console to see what errors are reported?

Comment: Avoid using W3Schools) as a reference..Their information is flawed - http://w3fools.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than describing the context like this, I'd encourage you to formulate the post as a simple, self-contained example: replace "prevNumber is for example 39203" with "prevNumber = 39203" in the code snippet. This way people can get to investigating with tools like [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net), etc and help you quickly. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more pointers on how to ask.

Comment: Mike W - Thank you for the fiddle, it works in exactly the way I wanted the code to. Unfortunately the exact same code doesn't work in my script... so I'll take a look why. jfriend00 - No, I didn't look in the error console, but I will do when I run the script next. Thank you. kfsone - Thank you for the advice, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: jfriend00 - It says TypeError: oldVars.replace is not a function What does this mean?

Comment: @Programmer: Use `@` to send a notification to another user. It means that `oldVars` is a data type that doesn't have a `.replace()` method. In other words, it isn't a string.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/G7PQV/

You probably mistyped something.

Javascript:

```
var oldVars = "Product ID 39203";
var prevNumber = "39203";
var newNumber = "200";

alert(oldVars);
alert("change "+prevNumber+" to "+newNumber)
newVars = oldVars.replace(prevNumber,newNumber);
alert(newVars);
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you're trying to find an integer in a string. If you convert the numbers to strings first using `.toString()` it should work.

Example: http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/d448dbdf05c290feaddcdd510ec5d72d

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using toString(). Thank you for the example code.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. If the answer helped you fix your problem, I would really appreciate it if you gave it a thumbs up and set it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(oldVars);
alert("change "+prevNumber+" to "+newNumber)
newVars = oldVars.replace(prevNumber,newNumber);
alert(newVars);
```

Interesting. As manishie stated, you most likely misspelled something. When I encounter errors like this I usually give my code a once over and make sure that everything is 100% syntactically sound, even if whatever pattern I chose usually works.

So, my suggestion would be to add the ';' at the end of:

```
alert("change "+prevNumber+" to "+newNumber)
```

Thus:

```
alert("change "+prevNumber+" to "+newNumber);
```

I've also encountered similar strange problems with the Revealing Module Pattern where typing:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    console.log( "Hehe!" );
});
```

Throws an error, while typing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "Hehe!" );
});
```

..does not.

Comment: The semicolon is not an issue, nor is having the opening `{` of a function on its own line.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't know why it doesn't work in my code, but I'll check for typing errors.

Comment: I'm aware of that user2736012, however, I've had errors from such things - especially with the RMP, is all that I'm trying to say. I'm not offering an answer, just a suggestion.